# Getting title and author from library open api?

Tags: php, json, api

Here are my sample code below and open book api guide from : https://developers.naver.com/docs/search/book/

How can I change this code if I want to get only book title and author?

Is there anyone experienced to have used library or bookstore open api?

The code below shows all the results possible.

http://amhappy.net/naverbook.php

```
  <?php


  $client_id = "";
  $client_secret = "";
  $encText = urlencode("ubuntu");
  $url = "https://openapi.naver.com/v1/search/book.json?query=".$encText; // json 결과

  $is_post = false;
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, $is_post);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  $headers = array();
  $headers[] = "X-Naver-Client-Id: ".$client_id;
  $headers[] = "X-Naver-Client-Secret: ".$client_secret;
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
  $response = curl_exec ($ch);
  $status_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
  echo "status_code:".$status_code."
";
  curl_close ($ch);
  if($status_code == 200) {
    echo $response;
  } else {
    echo "Error 내용:".$response;
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method will use `json_decode()`, a loop, and `array_intersect_key()` to retain only wanted elements from your response.  The `items` subarray holds all of the data (and more).  Overwriting `$v` by reference `&` allows you to filter out unwanted elements based on keys.

Code:

```
$json='{ "lastBuildDate": "Sat, 19 Aug 2017 22:35:30 +0900", "total": 861, "start": 1, "display": 10, "items": [ { "title": "ìœ ë‹‰ìŠ¤ ë¦¬ëˆ…ìŠ¤ ì…¸ ìŠ¤í¬ë¦½íŠ¸ ì˜ˆì œ ì‚¬ì „ (ì „ë¬¸ê°€ì—ê²Œ ê¼­ í•„ìš”í•œ 132ê°€ì§€ ì‹¤ìš© ì˜ˆì œ)", "link": "http://book.naver.com/bookdb/book_detail.php?bid=9487573", "image": "http://bookthumb.phinf.naver.net/cover/094/875/09487573.jpg?type=m1&udate=20160615", "author": "ì˜¤ìŠ¤ë¯¸ ìœ ìŠ¤ì¼€", "price": "30000", "discount": "27000", "publisher": "í•œë¹›ë¯¸ë””ì–´", "pubdate": "20150901", "isbn": "8968482136 9788968482137", "description": "ì‹¤ì „ ì˜ˆì œë¥¼ ê³§ ë°”ë¡œ í˜„ì—…ì— ì ìš©í•˜ë¼![ìœ ë‹‰ìŠ¤ ë¦¬ëˆ…ìŠ¤ ì…¸ ìŠ¤í¬ë¦½íŠ¸ ì˜ˆì œ ì‚¬ì „]ì€ ì„œë²„ ê´€ë¦¬, ë„¤íŠ¸ì›Œí¬ ê´€ë¦¬ ë“± ì‹¤ë¬´ì— ìœ ìš©í•œ ì‹¤ì „ ì‰˜ ìŠ¤í¬ë¦½íŠ¸ ì˜ˆì œë¥¼ 132ê°œ ì œê³µí•œë‹¤. ì„œë²„ ë° ë„¤íŠ¸ì›Œí¬ ê´€ë¦¬ìžë¿ë§Œ ì•„ë‹ˆë¼ ìœ ë‹‰ìŠ¤ì™€ ë¦¬ëˆ…ìŠ¤ ê°œë°œ í˜„ìž¥ì˜ ì¼ì›ì´ë¼ë©´ ì´ ì±…ì´ ì—…ë¬´ì— ìœ ìš©í•˜ê²Œ í™œìš©ë  ê²ƒì´ë‹¤. ì´ ì±…ì˜ ì˜ˆì œëŠ”... " }, { "title": "ìœ ë‹‰ìŠ¤ ì‹œìŠ¤í…œ í”„ë¡œê·¸ëž˜ë°", "link": "http://book.naver.com/bookdb/book_detail.php?bid=12321085", "image": "http://bookthumb.phinf.naver.net/cover/123/210/12321085.jpg?type=m1&udate=20170814", "author": "ì´ì¢…ì›", "price": "25000", "discount": "23250", "publisher": "í•œë¹›ì•„ì¹´ë°ë¯¸", "pubdate": "20170717", "isbn": "1156643325 9791156643326", "description": "ì•„, ì´ í•¨ìˆ˜ëŠ” ì´ëŸ´ ë•Œ ì“°ëŠ”êµ¬ë‚˜!ì˜ˆì œë¡œ ë°°ìš°ëŠ” ì‹œìŠ¤í…œ í˜¸ì¶œ í•¨ìˆ˜ì˜ ê°œë…ê³¼ ì›ë¦¬ ã€Žìœ ë‹‰ìŠ¤ ì‹œìŠ¤í…œ í”„ë¡œê·¸ëž˜ë°ã€. ì²˜ìŒ ì‹œìŠ¤í…œ í”„ë¡œê·¸ëž˜ë°ì„ ë°°ìš¸ ë•ŒëŠ” í•´ë‹¹... ì´ ì±…ì€ ìœ ë‹‰ìŠ¤ì˜ ë™ìž‘ ì›ë¦¬ë¿ë§Œ ì•„ë‹ˆë¼ ìœ ë‹‰ìŠ¤ ì‹œìŠ¤í…œì—ì„œ ì œê³µí•˜ëŠ” í•¨ìˆ˜ì˜ ì›í˜•ê³¼ ê°ê°ì˜ ì¸ìžë“¤ì„ ì†Œê°œí•œë‹¤. ë˜í•œ ê°œë…ì„ í™œìš©í•˜ëŠ” ì˜ˆì œë¥¼ ì œì‹œí•˜ì—¬... " }, { "title": "ìœ ë‹‰ìŠ¤ ë¦¬ëˆ…ìŠ¤ ëª…ë ¹ì–´ ì‚¬ì „", "link": "http://book.naver.com/bookdb/book_detail.php?bid=6413239", "image": "http://bookthumb.phinf.naver.net/cover/064/132/06413239.jpg?type=m1&udate=20170103", "author": "ìš°ì¢…ê²½|ë°•ì¢…ì˜¤", "price": "32000", "discount": "28800", "publisher": "í•œë¹›ë¯¸ë””ì–´", "pubdate": "20101130", "isbn": "8979147937 9788979147933", "description": "ë¹ ë¥´ê²Œ ì°¾ì•„ ì‰½ê²Œ í™œìš©í•  ìˆ˜ ìžˆëŠ” ìœ ë‹‰ìŠ¤ ë¦¬ëˆ…ìŠ¤ ëª…ë ¹ì–´ ì‚¬ì „ì´ë‹¤. ì¼ë°˜ ëª…ë ¹ì–´, ë°ëª¬ ë° ì„œë²„ì„¤ì •, RPM & DEB, VI ì—ë””í„°, SVN & Git, ì‰˜ ìŠ¤í¬ë¦½íŠ¸ í”„ë¡œê·¸ëž˜ë°ìœ¼ë¡œ ë¶„ë¥˜í•˜ì—¬ ìžì„¸ížˆ ë‹¤ë£¬ë‹¤. ì´ ì±…ì€ ëª…ë ¹ì–´ì˜ ì •í™•í•œ ì´ë¦„ì„ ëª°ë¼ë„ ì–´ë””ì— ì“°ì´ëŠ”ì§€ ì•Œë©´ í•„ìš”í•œ ëª…ë ¹ì–´ë¥¼ ì°¾ì„ ìˆ˜ ìžˆê²Œ \'ì´ë¦„ë³„ ì°¾ê¸°... " }, { "title": "ìœ ë‹‰ìŠ¤ ì´ë¡ ê³¼ ì‹¤ìŠµ (ìœ ë‹‰ìŠ¤ ì „ë¬¸ê°€ë¡œ ê°€ëŠ” ì²« ê±¸ìŒ)", "link": "http://book.naver.com/bookdb/book_detail.php?bid=7276858", "image": "http://bookthumb.phinf.naver.net/cover/072/768/07276858.jpg?type=m1&udate=20170316", "author": "ìš´ì†Œì •|ì´ì¢…ì›", "price": "23000", "discount": "21850", "publisher": "í•œë¹›ë¯¸ë””ì–´", "pubdate": "20130730", "isbn": "899875651X 9788998756512", "description": "ã€Žìœ ë‹‰ìŠ¤ ì´ë¡ ê³¼ ì‹¤ìŠµã€ì€ ìœ ë‹‰ìŠ¤ë‚˜ ë¦¬ëˆ…ìŠ¤ì— ëŒ€í•œ ê¸°ë³¸ ì§€ì‹ì„ ë°°ìš°ê³ ìž í•˜ëŠ” ì»´í“¨í„° ê´€ë ¨í•™ê³¼ì˜ í•™ë¶€ìƒì„ ëŒ€ìƒìœ¼ë¡œ í•œë‹¤. ìœ ë‹‰ìŠ¤ ìž…ë¬¸ì— ê¼­ í•„ìš”í•œ ê¸°ë³¸ ê¸°ëŠ¥ê³¼ ëª…ë ¹ì˜ ì‚¬ìš© ë°©ë²•ì„ ì˜ˆì œì™€ í•¨ê»˜ ìžì„¸ížˆ ì„¤ëª…í•˜ì˜€ê¸° ë•Œë¬¸ì— ìœ ë‹‰ìŠ¤ ê°•ì˜ êµìž¬ë¡œ ì í•©í•˜ë©°, ë…í•™ìš©ìœ¼ë¡œë„ í™œìš©í•  ìˆ˜ ìžˆë‹¤." }, { "title": "ìœ ë‹‰ìŠ¤ & ë¦¬ëˆ…ìŠ¤ ìž…ë¬¸ í•µì‹¬ ê°€ì´ë“œ (í…Œí¬ë„·ê³¼ í•¨ê»˜í•˜ëŠ”, ì—”í„°í”„ë¼ì´ì¦ˆ ì†”ë¼ë¦¬ìŠ¤ 11ìœ¼ë¡œ ë°°ìš°ëŠ”)", "link": "http://book.naver.com/bookdb/book_detail.php?bid=10371745", "image": "http://bookthumb.phinf.naver.net/cover/103/717/10371745.jpg?type=m1&udate=20161223", "author": "ê¹€ì„", "price": "20000", "discount": "18000", "publisher": "INTEK", "pubdate": "20160310", "isbn": "8996376051 9788996376057", "description": "ìœ ë‹‰ìŠ¤ ë° ë¦¬ëˆ…ìŠ¤ ìž…ë¬¸ìžë“¤ì„ ìœ„í•œ í•µì‹¬ ë‚´ìš©ì„ ì •ë¦¬í•˜ê³ , íœ´ëŒ€ê°€ ê°„íŽ¸í•˜ê²Œ ê°„ì¶”ë ¸ë‹¤. ì†”ë¼ë¦¬ìŠ¤ 11ì„ ê¸°ì¤€ìœ¼ë¡œ ìµœì‹  ë²„ì „ì˜ ìœ ë‹‰ìŠ¤ì™€ ë¦¬ëˆ…ìŠ¤ê°€ ëª¨ë‘ í¬í•¨ëœ ê³µí†µ ë‚´ìš©ì„ ê¸°ìˆ í–ˆë‹¤. ìœ ë‹‰ìŠ¤ ë° ë¦¬ëˆ…ìŠ¤ ì‹œìŠ¤í…œ ê´€ë¦¬ìžë‚˜ ê°œë°œìž, IT ê´€ë ¨ ë¶€ì„œ ì‹ ìž…ì‚¬ì›ì´ë‚˜ ì»´í“¨í„° ê´€ë ¨ í•™ê³¼ í•™ë¶€ìƒì—ê²Œ ì í•©í•˜ë‹¤." }, { "title": "ìœ ë‹‰ìŠ¤ ë¦¬ëˆ…ìŠ¤ ì‚¬ìš©ì—ì„œ í”„ë¡œê·¸ëž˜ë°ê¹Œì§€ (ì´ˆë³´ìžë¥¼ ìœ„í•œ ìœ ë‹‰ìŠ¤ ë° ë¦¬ëˆ…ìŠ¤ ì‹œìŠ¤í…œ í”„ë¡œê·¸ëž˜ë°)", "link": "http://book.naver.com/bookdb/book_detail.php?bid=6958195", "image": "http://bookthumb.phinf.naver.net/cover/069/581/06958195.jpg?type=m1&udate=20150715", "author": "ì°½ë³‘ëª¨", "price": "24000", "discount": "22800", "publisher": "ìƒëŠ¥ì¶œíŒì‚¬", "pubdate": "20120705", "isbn": "8970507345 9788970507347", "description": "ì´ˆë³´ìžë¥¼ ìœ„í•œ ìœ ë‹‰ìŠ¤ ë° ë¦¬ëˆ…ìŠ¤ ì‹œìŠ¤í…œ í”„ë¡œê·¸ëž˜ë°ã€Žìœ ë‹‰ìŠ¤Â·ë¦¬ëˆ…ìŠ¤ ì‚¬ìš©ì—ì„œ í”„ë¡œê·¸ëž˜ë°ê¹Œì§€ã€. ìœ ë‹‰ìŠ¤ ë° ë¦¬ëˆ…ìŠ¤ ì‹œìŠ¤í…œì— ëŒ€í•œ ì‚¬ìš©ë²•ê³¼ ì‹œìŠ¤í…œ í”„ë¡œê·¸ëž˜ë°ì„ ì²´ê³„ì ìœ¼ë¡œ ë°°ìš¸ ìˆ˜ ìžˆë„ë¡ êµ¬ì„±ëœ ì±…ì´ë‹¤. ë³¸ë¬¸ì˜ ì „ë°˜ë¶€ì—ì„œëŠ” ìœ ë‹‰ìŠ¤Â·ë¦¬ëˆ…ìŠ¤ ì‹œìŠ¤í…œì˜ ì‚¬ìš© ë° í™œìš©ì„ ì¤‘ì‹¬ìœ¼ë¡œ ê³µë¶€í•  ìˆ˜ ìžˆë„ë¡... " }, { "title": "ìœ ë‹‰ìŠ¤ ì‹œìŠ¤í…œ í”„ë¡œê·¸ëž˜ë°", "link": "http://book.naver.com/bookdb/book_detail.php?bid=6217299", "image": "http://bookthumb.phinf.naver.net/cover/062/172/06217299.jpg?type=m1&udate=20150723", "author": "ì´ì¢…ì›", "price": "25000", "discount": "25000", "publisher": "í•œë¹›ë¯¸ë””ì–´", "pubdate": "20100107", "isbn": "8979147155 9788979147155", "description": "150ê°œ ì˜ˆì œë¡œ ìœ ë‹‰ìŠ¤ ì‹œìŠ¤í…œ í˜¸ì¶œ í•¨ìˆ˜ë¥¼ ì •ë³µí•œë‹¤ã€Žìœ ë‹‰ìŠ¤ ì‹œìŠ¤í…œ í”„ë¡œê·¸ëž˜ë°ã€ì€ ìœ ë‹‰ìŠ¤ì˜ ë™ìž‘ ì›ë¦¬ë¿ë§Œ ì•„ë‹ˆë¼ ìœ ë‹‰ìŠ¤ ì‹œìŠ¤í…œì—ì„œ ì œê³µí•˜ëŠ” í•¨ìˆ˜ì˜ ì›í˜•ê³¼ ê°ê°ì˜ ì¸ì§€ë“¤ì„ ì†Œê°œí•œë‹¤. ë˜í•œ ê°œë…ì„ í™œìš©í•˜ëŠ” ì˜ˆì œë¥¼ ì œì‹œí•˜ì—¬ ì²˜ìŒ ì ‘í•œ í•¨ìˆ˜ì¼ì§€ë¼ë„ ì–¸ì œ ì–´ë–»ê²Œ ì‚¬ìš©í•˜ëŠ”ì§€ ìžì—°ìŠ¤ëŸ½ê²Œ ì´í•´í•  ìˆ˜ ìžˆë‹¤." }, { "title": "ìœ ë‹‰ìŠ¤ ê´€ë¦¬ìžë¥¼ ìœ„í•œ ì—”í„°í”„ë¼ì´ì¦ˆ ì†”ë¼ë¦¬ìŠ¤ í•µì‹¬ ìš´ì˜ ê°€ì´ë“œ (í…Œí¬ë„·ê³¼ í•¨ê»˜í•˜ëŠ”)", "link": "http://book.naver.com/bookdb/book_detail.php?bid=6248536", "image": "http://bookthumb.phinf.naver.net/cover/062/485/06248536.jpg?type=m1&udate=20161225", "author": "ê¹€ì„|ìž¥ì„±ê· ", "price": "32000", "discount": "28800", "publisher": "ë¹„íŒ¬ë¶ìŠ¤", "pubdate": "20100312", "isbn": "8996204560 9788996204565", "description": "ìœ ë‹‰ìŠ¤ì—ëŠ” ë¦¬ëˆ…ìŠ¤ì™€ ê°™ì€ ë²”ìš©ì„±ì˜ íŠ¹ì§•ì´ ìžˆë‹¤. ë” ë‚˜ì•„ê°€ì„œ ì•ˆì •ì„±ê³¼ ë‹¤ì–‘ì„±ê³¼ í™•ìž¥ì„±ê³¼ ë³´ì•ˆì„±ê¹Œì§€ ê°–ì¶”ê³  ìžˆë‹¤. ë˜í•œ, ê¸°ì—…ê³¼ ì •ë¶€ ì¡°ì§ì—ì„œ ìœ ë‹‰ìŠ¤ê°€ ìš´ìš©ë˜ê³  ìžˆì§€ ì•Šì€ ê³³ì€ ê±°ì˜ ì—†ì„ ê²ƒì´ë‹¤. ê·¸ ë§Œí¼ ì‹œìŠ¤í…œ ì—”ì§€ë‹ˆì–´ê°€ ë˜ê¸° ìœ„í•´ì„œëŠ” ì–´ë–¤ ë²¤ë”ì˜ ê²ƒì´ë“  ìœ ë‹‰ìŠ¤ì— ëŒ€í•œ ìš´ìš© ìŠ¤í‚¬ì„ í™•ë³´í•˜ê³  ìžˆì–´ì•¼... " }, { "title": "ìœ ë‹‰ìŠ¤ ì‹œìŠ¤í…œ ë„¤íŠ¸ì›Œí¬ í”„ë¡œê·¸ëž˜ë° (ì‹¤ì „ì—ì„œ ì¨ë¨¹ëŠ”)", "link": "http://book.naver.com/bookdb/book_detail.php?bid=7405657", "image": "http://bookthumb.phinf.naver.net/cover/074/056/07405657.jpg?type=m1&udate=20170216", "author": "ì‹ ìž¬í˜¸|ê¹€ì˜ìµ", "price": "30000", "discount": "27000", "publisher": "ì˜ì§„ë‹·ì»´", "pubdate": "20140102", "isbn": "8931445881 9788931445886", "description": "ìœ ë‹‰ìŠ¤ë¥¼ ì¢€ ë” íš¨ìœ¨ì ìœ¼ë¡œ í™œìš©í•  ìˆ˜ ìžˆë„ë¡ ë•ê³ ìž í•œë‹¤. ìœ ë‹‰ìŠ¤ë¥¼ ì²˜ìŒ ì ‘í•˜ëŠ” ë…ìžë“¤ì„ ìœ„í•´ í•„ížˆ ìµí˜€ì•¼ í•˜ëŠ” ìœ ë‹‰ìŠ¤ì˜ ê°œë…ê³¼ Cì™€ C++ ê´€ë ¨ ë¶€ë¶„ì„ ì¶”ê°€í•´ ìœ ë‹‰ìŠ¤ë¥¼ ì‰½ê²Œ ë°°ìš¸ ìˆ˜ ìžˆë„ë¡ í•˜ì˜€ìœ¼ë©° ë‚˜ì¤‘ì—ëŠ” ì‹¤ì œ í”„ë¡œì íŠ¸ì™€ ìœ ì‚¬í•˜ê²Œ ì˜ˆì œ ì‹œìŠ¤í…œì„ êµ¬í˜„í•´ë³´ëŠ” ìžë¦¬ë„ ë§ˆë ¨í•˜ì˜€ë‹¤. íŠ¹ížˆ ìœ ë‹‰ìŠ¤ ì‹œìŠ¤í…œê³¼... " }, { "title": "ìœ ë‹‰ìŠ¤ Cì‰˜ í”„ë¡œê·¸ëž˜ë°", "link": "http://book.naver.com/bookdb/book_detail.php?bid=7446011", "image": "http://bookthumb.phinf.naver.net/cover/074/460/07446011.jpg?type=m1&udate=20150211", "author": "í™©ë¯¼íƒœ", "price": "18000", "discount": "16920", "publisher": "í•œì‚°", "pubdate": "20140220", "isbn": "8989215943 9788989215943", "description": "ã€Žìœ ë‹‰ìŠ¤ Cì‰˜ í”„ë¡œê·¸ëž˜ë°ã€ì€ 16ì£¼ ê°•ì˜ë¡œ êµ¬ì„±ë˜ëŠ” ëŒ€í•™êµ ê°•ì˜ êµìž¬ì— ì´ˆì ì„ ë§žì¶”ì—ˆìœ¼ë©°, ì¼ë°˜ì¸ì´ë¼ í• ì§€ë¼ë„ ì˜ˆì œë¥¼ ì¤‘ì‹¬ìœ¼ë¡œ ì¡°ê¸ˆì”© ë°°ìš°ë‹¤ ë³´ë©´ ì§§ì€ ì‹œê°„ë‚´ì— ë§ˆìŠ¤í„°í•  ìˆ˜ ìžˆë„ë¡ êµ¬ì„±í•˜ì˜€ë‹¤. ì´ 9ìž¥ìœ¼ë¡œ êµ¬ì„±í•˜ì—¬, ìœ ë‹‰ìŠ¤ ì‹¤ìŠµ í™˜ê²½ êµ¬ì¶•ë¶€í„° ê¸°íƒ€ ìœ ë‹‰ìŠ¤ ëª…ë ¹ì–´ê¹Œì§€ ì‚´íŽ´ë³¸ë‹¤." } ] }';
$array=json_decode($json,true)['items'];
foreach($array as &$v){
    $v=array_intersect_key($v,['title'=>'','author'=>'']);
}
var_export($array);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'title' => 'ìœ ë‹‰ìŠ¤ ë¦¬ëˆ…ìŠ¤ ì…¸ ìŠ¤í¬ë¦½íŠ¸ ì˜ˆì œ ì‚¬ì „ (ì „ë¬¸ê°€ì—ê²Œ ê¼­ í•„ìš”í•œ 132ê°€ì§€ ì‹¤ìš© ì˜ˆì œ)',
    'author' => 'ì˜¤ìŠ¤ë¯¸ ìœ ìŠ¤ì¼€',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'title' => 'ìœ ë‹‰ìŠ¤ ì‹œìŠ¤í…œ í”„ë¡œê·¸ëž˜ë°',
    'author' => 'ì´ì¢…ì›',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'title' => 'ìœ ë‹‰ìŠ¤ ë¦¬ëˆ…ìŠ¤ ëª…ë ¹ì–´ ì‚¬ì „',
    'author' => 'ìš°ì¢…ê²½|ë°•ì¢…ì˜¤',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'title' => 'ìœ ë‹‰ìŠ¤ ì´ë¡ ê³¼ ì‹¤ìŠµ (ìœ ë‹‰ìŠ¤ ì „ë¬¸ê°€ë¡œ ê°€ëŠ” ì²« ê±¸ìŒ)',
    'author' => 'ìš´ì†Œì •|ì´ì¢…ì›',
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    'title' => 'ìœ ë‹‰ìŠ¤ & ë¦¬ëˆ…ìŠ¤ ìž…ë¬¸ í•µì‹¬ ê°€ì´ë“œ (í…Œí¬ë„·ê³¼ í•¨ê»˜í•˜ëŠ”, ì—”í„°í”„ë¼ì´ì¦ˆ ì†”ë¼ë¦¬ìŠ¤ 11ìœ¼ë¡œ ë°°ìš°ëŠ”)',
    'author' => 'ê¹€ì„',
  ),
  5 => 
  array (
    'title' => 'ìœ ë‹‰ìŠ¤ ë¦¬ëˆ…ìŠ¤ ì‚¬ìš©ì—ì„œ í”„ë¡œê·¸ëž˜ë°ê¹Œì§€ (ì´ˆë³´ìžë¥¼ ìœ„í•œ ìœ ë‹‰ìŠ¤ ë° ë¦¬ëˆ…ìŠ¤ ì‹œìŠ¤í…œ í”„ë¡œê·¸ëž˜ë°)',
    'author' => 'ì°½ë³‘ëª¨',
  ),
  6 => 
  array (
    'title' => 'ìœ ë‹‰ìŠ¤ ì‹œìŠ¤í…œ í”„ë¡œê·¸ëž˜ë°',
    'author' => 'ì´ì¢…ì›',
  ),
  7 => 
  array (
    'title' => 'ìœ ë‹‰ìŠ¤ ê´€ë¦¬ìžë¥¼ ìœ„í•œ ì—”í„°í”„ë¼ì´ì¦ˆ ì†”ë¼ë¦¬ìŠ¤ í•µì‹¬ ìš´ì˜ ê°€ì´ë“œ (í…Œí¬ë„·ê³¼ í•¨ê»˜í•˜ëŠ”)',
    'author' => 'ê¹€ì„|ìž¥ì„±ê· ',
  ),
  8 => 
  array (
    'title' => 'ìœ ë‹‰ìŠ¤ ì‹œìŠ¤í…œ ë„¤íŠ¸ì›Œí¬ í”„ë¡œê·¸ëž˜ë° (ì‹¤ì „ì—ì„œ ì¨ë¨¹ëŠ”)',
    'author' => 'ì‹ ìž¬í˜¸|ê¹€ì˜ìµ',
  ),
  9 => 
  array (
    'title' => 'ìœ ë‹‰ìŠ¤ Cì‰˜ í”„ë¡œê·¸ëž˜ë°',
    'author' => 'í™©ë¯¼íƒœ',
  ),
)
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll try anyway.